# How to combine [JsonPropertyName] and [ObservableProperty] on the same member?

Tags: c#, json, winui-3, system.text.json, community-toolkit-mvvm

I'm trying to combine `[JsonPropertyName]` with `[ObservableProperty]` to assign the value "last_updated" of my json to the property "Updated" of my object.

I tried this code:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
[JsonPropertyName("last_updated")]
public string updated;
```

But **it is not working: 'Updated' is null after deserializing**.

What should be the correct way to handle this?

An example of my JSON:

```json
[{"id":1,"username":"******","password":"******","email":"*****","created":"2023-12-19 19:28:23","last_updated":"2023-12-19 19:28:23","address":"*******","full_name":"*******","last_login":{"id":1,"user_id":1,"ip_address":"******","result_code":"0","result":"Success"},"role":"Admin"}]
```

Project details:

- WinUI 3
- System.Text.Json 8.0.0
- CommunityToolkit.Mvvm 8.2.2
- .NET 6.0

I add a screenshot showing the inspection:

[image: Screenshot of debugger]

Full class code:

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RotaPro.Models;

public partial class Dipendente : ObservableObject
{

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int id;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string username;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string email;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string created;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [JsonPropertyName("last_updated")]
    public string updated;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string address;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [JsonPropertyName("full_name")]
    private string fullName;

    public Dipendente()
    {

    }

    public Dipendente(int id, string username, string email, string created, string updated, string address, string fullName)
    {
        Id = id;
        Username = username;
        Email = email;
        Created = created;
        Updated = updated;
        Address = address;
        FullName = fullName;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FullName;
    }

}
```

Deserialization code:

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
using RotaPro.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using Serilog;

namespace RotaPro.Classes;

public class ApiClient
{

    private static RestClient _instance;
    private static bool _initialized = false;

    public ApiClient()
    {
        
    }

    public void Initialize(string username, string apiKey)
    {
        if (_instance is not null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ApiClient già inizializzato");

        RestClientOptions options = new RestClientOptions("https://*****/***/**/")
        {
            Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, apiKey)
        };

        _instance = new RestClient(options);
        _initialized = true;
    }

    public static async Task<List<Dipendente>> GetDipendenti()
    {
        if (!_initialized)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ApiClient non inizializzato");

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/user/all");
        RestResponse response = await _instance.ExecuteAsync(request);

        if(!response.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException($"Errore {response.StatusCode} durante la richiesta");
        }

        string json = response.Content;
        Log.Debug($"Ricevuto: {json}");

        JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        };

        List<Dipendente> lista = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Dipendente>>(json, options)!;

        return lista;
    }

}
```

Comment: System.Text.Json only serializes **properties** by default, but `public string updated;` is a **field**.  Try changing to a property by doing `public string updated { get; set; }`

Comment: @dbc That will break the `[ObservableProperty]` source generator, it can only be applied to fields and automatically generates properties. I'm afraid it's not possible to combine those attributes/generators.

Comment: @dbc Thanks for your comment. I added the full Class as text instead of image. I'm not serializing the object because I'm getting the json from an external API, I just need to deserialize it.

Comment: @dbc I tried changing with `public string updated { get; set; }` but I'm getting an error: `CS0592 Attribute 'ObservableProperty' is not valid in this type of declaration. It is valid only in 'field' declarations.`

Comment: @Julian How do you suggest me to workaround this?

Comment: @TimoFran See my answer. I'm afraid you cannot use both together since they work on different member types.

Comment: @TimoFran - you might be able to use a customized contract.  Or you might be able to do something with the JSON source generator.  Will need to think a bit.

Comment: What .NET version are you using?

Comment: @dbc I'm using .NET 6.0

Comment: That is unfortunate.  Contract customization was introduced in .NET 7, so you have far fewer options in .NET 6.  Do you need to do serialization, or only deserialization?

Comment: The CommunityToolkit.Mvvm supports additional attributes. Check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **CommunityToolkit.Mvvm** support [this](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/issues/413). So you should be able to add attributes like this:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
[property: JsonPropertyName("last_updated")]
public string updated;
```

Answer (score 0):

just include in options IncludeFields and you will be happy

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
        IncludeFields=true
    };

    List<Dipendente> lista = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Dipendente>>(json, options)!;
```

but you  will have to make all fields public

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does not change the behaviour: all values are filled except 'Updated' and 'FullName' which are still null. Do I need to change something also in 'Dipendente' class?